# What API is using facebook to get the reach estimate for boosted posts?

Tags: facebook, facebook-marketing-api

We are building in my company a tool to manage Social Networks Accounts like facebook and twitter and we want to create tools for most of the important functions.

For facebook, I am in charge to create a tool to replicate the boost post feature on Facebook fan pages, but I can't find the that API they are using to get the reach estimated.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2M2x.png

I try tracking the call made by the dialog and I got some information:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UH6kQ.png

The point is that the URL used is not public accessible.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Have you read the [Marketing API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-apis) docs? Specifically, the [reachestimate documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reachestimate/v2.4)? This question seems to be too broad. Please edit your question to be about a concrete issue that you are having with the API.

Comment: @derabbink I already check the reach estimate endpoint, but that not return the same information. That is the reason of my question

Comment: That sounds like it could be a bug with Facebook, and you can consider filing a bug report for it at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs. Please make sure to include all information necessary for Facebook engineers to reproduce your bug, i.e. full API calls, API responses, and reasons why the responses are incorrect.

Comment: Facebook Marketing API reach estimate is extremely buggy or at least very unreliable. Facing a similar issue and have already filed a bug report